# Add Text to the Image

Tags: iphone, text, uiimageview, uiimage

HI

Im currently developing an application where i have to add the text over the image at any position in the image(not subview) and the output should be the single image file with the original image and the text embedded in it,any help will be appreciable.

eg : water mark on the image

Thanks
sivasankar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UIImage *myImage = loadUnwatermarkedImage();
NSString *myWatermarkText = @"Watermark";
UIImage *watermarkedImage = nil;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myImage.size);
[myImage drawAtPoint: CGPointZero];
[myWatermarkText drawAtPoint: CGPointMake(10, 10) withFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12]];
watermarkedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Upon completion the *watermarkedImage* will be an autoreleased watermarked image. *loadUnwatermarkedImage()* is a fictional function providing an original image.

Comment: Thanks Costique,it works.pls get your mail id to ask the doubt directly through mail / chat

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I used `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)` on my `UIView`.