# Writing text to a UIImage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I'm trying to write a number inside of an image of a block. I've been looking up how to do this, and I found a couple different ways to do it. Problem is, neither of them work. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250057/add-text-to-the-image) and [this](http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/05/05/Add-text-to-image-%28UIImage%29.aspx), but they both cause an error in the contact log that says `invalid context 0x0`. Anyone know what can cause that?

EDIT:

I should probably mention where I'm trying to implement this. I have a class called `Blok` that extends NSObject and holds a UIImage. That UIImage is used in another class's `drawRect` method, and is also what I want to have text on.

Here's where I initialize the image:

```
-(id)initWithType:(NSString*)theType andSymbol:(NSString*)theSymbol {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        image = [[UIImage alloc] init];

        type = theType;
        symbol = theSymbol;
    }
    return self;
}
```

And here is where it gets set later on:

```
-(void)setImage:(UIImage*)theImage {

    image = theImage;

    image = [self addText:symbol atPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12] ofColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

}
```

The method call is to the method shown below, given by H2CO3:

```
- (UIImage *) addText: (NSString *) str atPoint: (CGPoint) point withFont: (UIFont *) font ofColor: (UIColor *) color {

    int w = image.size.width;
    int h = image.size.height;

    // create empty bitmap context
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB ();
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL, w, h, 8, w * 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality (ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh);

    // draw the image and the text on the bitmap context
    CGContextDrawImage (ctx, CGRectMake (0, 0, h, w), image.CGImage);
    char *text = (char *)[str cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (ctx, kCGTextFill);
    CGFloat *comp = CGColorGetComponents ([color CGColor]);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (ctx, comp[0], comp[1], comp[2], comp[3]);
    CGContextSelectFont (ctx, [[font fontName] UTF8String], [font pointSize], kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint (ctx, point.x, h - point.y, text, strlen (text));

    // get the image as a UIImage and clean up
    CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageMasked];
    CGContextRelease (ctx);
    CGImageRelease (imageMasked);
    CGColorSpaceRelease (colorSpace);

    return img;

}
```

I tweaked it a bit to suit the program. Unfortunately, this seems to be causing a bad access error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dealing with this a little longer than I would like, I'm just going to use a UILabel in the `drawRect` method.

EDIT: Using `drawAtPoint` in the `drawRect` method, working just fine now.

Answer (score 2):

See how I implemented this here: https://github.com/H2CO3/UIImage-Editor/blob/master/UIImage%2BEditor.m

Especially, take a look at the

```
- (UIImage *) addText: (NSString *) str atPoint: (CGPoint) point withFont: (UIFont *) font ofColor: (UIColor *) color
```

method.

Comment: Okay, that seemed to work. It didn't like the `CGAffineTransform transform = [self transformForOrientation: self.size];`, so I took it out along with the lines that referenced it. Kept the drawImage line in, though. It passed by that without any real problems, but now I'm getting the dreaded `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error >_< I'll accept your answer when I can get around that error...

Comment: And when and where is that error occuring? The error is surely not in my code as it is tested and used several times. I help you solve this but you have to provide more information.

Comment: That's the problem, is that I can't pinpoint the part where it causes the error. I went through debugger, and it looks like the program is working fine, but it hits a line in the background code (not the code that I'm writing, but the 'under the hood' stuff) that causes the error.

Comment: I'm giving a +1 for the answer. The code definitely makes sense to me, but for whatever reason I'm getting a bad access error when I use it. I know because it runs fine if I take out the line that calls it. Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to be the one to my problem...

Comment: Okay, if you wish. If you could show me the relevant lines of your program, I may eventually be able to track down the problem. Btw do you use ARC?