# adding text to image within image picker

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa

hello i am creating an `iOS` app using `cocoa` and `xcode`

i am very new to the whole thing and have gotten kind of lost. 
in part of my application the user must choose a picture from the library or using a camera, then some text is added to it(just like "id cap that"). 
the question is where would i add the text and how do i save it to the phone?

i know there is a `allowsImageEditing` property, the question is how to i edit it so that instead of crop and zoom it will add text and have an option of saving.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system determines what kind of editing is allowed. You can only tell it whether it's allowed or not, but you cannot choose what type of editing. If you want to add a caption to an image, you'll have to use Core Graphics to do so. Or, if you don't care about the image being saved with the caption on it, you can simply use a UILabel on top of a UIImageView.

Comment: that's exactly what i want but the image isnt being saved with the caption when i do `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([imageView image],nil,nil,nil);`. any ideas?

Comment: That's because your label isn't part of your image. You would have to do some Core Graphics magic to actually make it part of the image, not just the image view. See this Stack Overflow thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250057/add-text-to-the-image